# Avoiding nested for loops to test parameters

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to optimise a model by varying multiple parameters and running the model multiple times. Example code below.

```
parameter_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
parameter_2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
parameter_3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]

for p1 in parameter_1:
    for p2 in parameter_2:
        for p3 in parameter_3:
            run_model(p1, p2, p3)
```

This runs fine and I accept that the model needs to be run a large number of times, there's no escaping that. However, I'd like to make the code more elegant if possible. In reality I'm varying 5 different parameters so it's even more nested than the above.

1. Is there any structure for looping through multiple lists that I'm not aware of?
2. If not, could I restructure the lists to use a different approach whilst maintaining legibility?

I have looked up similar answers on SE but they seem to be for specific cases which don't apply here. Apologies if I have overlooked the answer elsewhere.

Comment: There is no neat way of avoiding what you're doing. But you may want to rethink the model

Comment: It's not always effective to explore the whole search space

Comment: Agree on both of the above but consider this approach a series of test parameters to identify avenues for optimisation, and not a permanent structure. I can't think of an alternative to running the tests, without letting my existing prejudices of what 'should' be optimal come into play.

Comment: Mmm, then you'll need to clarify what you mean by your "prejudices" here.

Comment: I think I can see your desire for a structured test vs things that are inherently unstructured. You could set a seed for the RNG

Comment: By prejudices I just mean my existing and untested intuitions. I'd rather be methodical. What do you mean by setting 'a seed for the RNG'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing I understand correctly what your trying to accomplish you to run a function on all possible variations?

Did you try `itertools.product`?

```
import itertools

parameter_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
parameter_2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
parameter_3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]

for i in itertools.product(parameter_1, parameter_2, parameter_3):
   run_your_function(*i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `itertools` to remove your highly nested structure:

```
import itertools

def run_model(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c

if __name__=='__main__':
    parameter_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    parameter_2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
    parameter_3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]

    combinations = itertools.product(*[parameter_1, parameter_2, parameter_3])

    for c in combinations:
        print(run_model(*c))
```